# call a function after completely loaded into html with ng-repeate

Tags: json, angularjs

how can I call a function after completely loaded my json data from the server into a ng-repeate?

Ex: I have json URL it have some products data which is in my car, once I clicked on view cart the cart items should be showed in the popup box. and if add another product it should me added in the popup box.

Please help me guys

Comment: I would recommend reading into the source code... see if there are any clues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### HTML

```
<div data-ng-controller="MainController">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="asset in assets" my-directive>{{asset}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### JS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainController',function($scope) {
    $scope.assets = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]; 
});
app.value('myFunc',function(){
  alert('Hello');
});
app.directive('myDirective', function( myFunc) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
     link: function(scope, elem) {

        if (scope.$last){
          myFunc();
        }
    }
  };
});
```

It should work also with a asyn service (to get data)